# how to use react hook form validation onchange of the textfield in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

[form that i want to validate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI8GS.png)

i am seeing to validate these form in react hoook forms with mui component text field .
the problem is its validating the form on submit, but i need to validate it on change of the text field

```
const eventSchema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup
    .string()
    .max(128, requiredLimit)
    .required(requiredField)
    .nullable(),
});
```

```
const useFunction = useForm({
    defaultValues: defaultValue,
    resolver: yupResolver(eventSchema),
  });
  const { handleSubmit, reset, control, register, formState } = useFunction;
  const { errors } = formState;

  useEffect(() => {
    reset(defaultValue);
  }, [
    defaultValue.title,
  ]);
```

```
   <FormInputText
              name='title'
              type='text'
              control={control}
              label='Title'
              helperText={errors?.title?.message}
              errors={!!errors.title}
              register={register('title', {
                onChange: (e) => dispatch(setTitle(e.target.value)),
              })}
            />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add mode prop

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/

`mode: onChange | onBlur | onSubmit | onTouched | all = 'onSubmit'`

```
const useFunction = useForm({
    mode: 'onBlur', // new prop added
    defaultValues: defaultValue,
    resolver: yupResolver(eventSchema),
  });
```